# Passing variables from NODE (server side) to React (client side)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ejs

I've found a lot of threads on this but, after following them, I'm still having an issue where the variable is not made available to my React application.

My server-side script, "var/www/sendvars/server.js":

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});  
 
   var headers = JSON.stringify(request.headers);
   const userid = JSON.stringify(request.headers.userid);
  
  response.end(userid);
}).listen(8080);
```

I've also tried this with the EJS template renderer

```
var http = require("http");
let ejs = require('ejs');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});  
 
   var headers = JSON.stringify(request.headers);
   const userid  = JSON.stringify(request.headers.userid);
  var renderedHtml = ejs.render(userid, {userid: userid});
  response.end(renderedHtml);
}).listen(8080);
```

Both of the above return the userid as expected in the console and if I go to localhost:8080 in a browser.

In my react application, "var/www/html/reactapp/index.html" (viewed at http://localhost:3000/)

I have:

```
<script>  
   window.userid = '<%= userid%>'
 </script>
```

....but that results in the browser error:

```
 Html Webpack Plugin:        ReferenceError: userid is not defined
```

In my console, for the EJS attempt, I have:

```
 Template execution failed: ReferenceError: userid is not defined
```

Comment: Why does your server respond with `text/html` and then sends `userid` which for sure is not `text/html`. Any why do you pass `userid` as a template name to `ejs.render`?

Comment: I've tried many things.  I've also tried passing a test string, an array, an object, etc.  This is just the last thing I've tried.  I've also tried passing ('test', {userid: userid} to ejs.render.  Does the name of the template matter?  I've also tried ('index', {userid: 'testid'}).